# Проблемы с функцией RegEnumKeyEx() на Win7

Tags: windows, реестр, fasm

Пытаюсь собрать список установленных в системе программ.
Начал с функций `MsiEnumProducts()` + `MsiGetProductInfo()` из библиотеки msi.dll, но они возвращают только те программы, которые имеют GUID, т.е. исключительно продукты Microsoft. В результате список получается не полный - в моём случае всего 25 программ из 103.

Для решения этой проблемы в гугле советуют перечислить (под)ключи в ветке реестра: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`, где вижу все установленные программы, но теперь функция `RegEnumKeyEx()` возвращает только пару программ от сторонних производителей, и в упор невидит те, которые зарегистрированны с GUID. На выходе в цикле она возвращает **ERROR_MORE_DATA** с кодом `0x00EA`, мол есть ещё данные, но в буфер **"lpName"** сбрасывает имя подраздела в одном случае из 20-ти. Пишу на ассме и код выглядит так:

```
;// Открыть раздел реестра
         invoke  RegOpenKeyEx,HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,\
                            <'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall',0>,0,\
                              KEY_QUERY_VALUE + KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS,\
                              hKey

;// Получить кол-во подразделов
         invoke  RegQueryInfoKeyA,[hKey],0,0,0,subKey,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
        cinvoke  printf,<10,' Uninstall. Total subkey = %d',\
                         10,' -----------------------------',10,0>,[subKey]

         dec     [subKey]      ;//<----- Индекс для цикла 

;// Цикл перечисления (под)разделов "Uninstall"
@@:      mov     ecx,256/4     ;//<----- очистить приёмный буфер
         xor     eax,eax
         mov     edi,lpName
         rep     stosd

         invoke  RegEnumKeyEx,[hKey],[subKey],lpName,nameLen,0,0,0,0
         invoke  CharToOem,lpName,lpName
        cinvoke  printf,<10,' SubKey:  %s'>,lpName
         dec     [subKey]      ;//<----- следующий индекс.. (обратный отсчёт)
         jnz     @b
```

Хоть и запускаю код под админом, пробовал устанавливать себе и различные привилегии типа **"SeSecurityPrivilege"** и прочие, менял флаги в `RegOpenKeyEx()` - всё бесполезно. На данный момент картина такая.. Буду благодарен за любые советы. Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Конечно понятно, что задачи могут быть разными, но глаз Одина, работа с реестром через ассемблер!? Зачем такие сложности?

Comment: В документации https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regenumkeyexa написано: ``If the lpName buffer is too small to receive the name of the key, the function returns ERROR_MORE_DATA.`` Я бы на вашем месте увеличил размер буфера до 4096 символов.

Comment: @Blackmeser  никаких сложностей с языком не испытываю, тем более вся программа на ассме. И к сожалению увеличение буфера не помогло. В принципе его размер должен быть не меньше макс.длинны строки с именем подраздела, и 4К под имя - это уж слишком.

Comment: Тогда советую проверить nameLen дебаггером на каждой итерации цикла, вы же его указателем в RegOpenKeyEx передаёте? Может RegOpenKeyEx его значение меняет.

Comment: `Тогда советую проверить nameLen` - и точно из-за этого! Добавил внутри цикла обновление этой переменной, и всё ОК! Большое вам спасибо!

Comment: Тогда оформите пожалуйста ответ, как вы это исправили и отметьте как решение, по ассемблеру в инете и так информации с проблемами мало, большинство из тех тематических форумов что было - уже либо мертвы либо поисковики никак не помогут найти, может ещё кому-то поможет.

Comment: PS да, действительно стало логичнее, ведь когда в буфер происходит запись строки, куда-то должна записаться информация о новой длине строки, чтобы не было такого что ``"Индиана Джонс_____________"`` или ``"Индиана Джонс Империя наносит ответный удар"``, крч. чтобы вы знали новую длину строки в буфере, при этом я предполагаю, что сам буфер строки очищать не требуется на каждой итерации, что является плюсом в плане скорости.

Answer (score 1):

@Blackmeser указал мне на возможную ошибку, и проблема решилась. Оказывается функция `RegEnumKeyEx()` на каждой итерации цикла перезаписывает содержимое переменной **"lpcName"**, сбрасывая в неё длину имени текущего найденного (под)раздела. Собственно и MSDN об этом сообщает прямым текстом, но я не обратил внимания:

> Если функция завершается успешно, переменная, на которую указывает lpcName, содержит кол-во символов, хранящихся в буфере, не включая завершающий нулевой символ.

Поэтому нужно внутри цикла постоянно обновлять её содержимое, выставляя на макс.256, в соответствии с размером выделенного буфера. Вот исправленный вариант моего кода на ассемблере FASM, и остаётся только считывать значение **"DisplayName"** в каждом подразделе:

```
format   pe console
entry    start
;//-------
section  '.inc' data readable
include  'win32ax.inc'
include  'equates\advapi32.inc'
;//-------
.data
hKey        dd  0
subKey      dd  0
index       dd  0
counter     dd  1

align 16
lpName      rb  256
nameLen     dd  256
buff        db  0
;//---------
.code
start:   invoke  SetConsoleTitle,<'*** Programm List v1.0 ***',0>

;// Открыть раздел реестра
         invoke  RegOpenKeyEx,HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,\
                            <'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall',0>,0,\
                              KEY_QUERY_VALUE + KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS,\
                              hKey
;// Вычислить кол-во подразделов
         invoke  RegQueryInfoKeyA,[hKey],0,0,0,subKey,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
        cinvoke  printf,<10,' Uninstall. Total subkey = %d',\
                         10,' -----------------------------',10,0>,[subKey]
         dec     [subKey]

@@:      mov     ecx,256/4       ;//<---- Очистить буф
         xor     eax,eax
         mov     edi,lpName
         rep     stosd
         mov     [nameLen],256   ;//<---- Ошибка была здесь! Размер на макс.

         invoke  RegEnumKeyEx,[hKey],[subKey],lpName,nameLen,0,0,0,0
         invoke  CharToOem,lpName,lpName
        cinvoke  printf,<10,' %03d.  %s'>,[counter],lpName

         inc     [counter]       ;//<---- Счётчик найденных +1
         dec     [subKey]        ;//<---- Следующий индекс..
         cmp     [subKey],-1     ;//<---- Переполнение индекса?
         jnz     @b              ;//<---- Нет: повторить.

@exit:  cinvoke  _getch
        cinvoke  exit,0
;//-------
section '.idata' import data readable
library   msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll',kernel32,'kernel32.dll',user32,'user32.dll',\
          advapi32,'advapi32.dll'
include  'api\msvcrt.inc'
include  'api\kernel32.inc'
include  'api\user32.inc'
include  'api\advapi32.inc'
```